# Cannot fire the scroll event in mobile view reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I have been trying to do a simple code which can fire a scroll event in mobile view (responsive).

The event fires correctly when the window is greater than 768px.
But when it is in mobile view, it does not work well. Is it s problem with react.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class MyComp extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

this.state = {};
this.handleScroll = this.handleScroll.bind(this);


}



componentWillMount() {
    // window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleSroll);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
    document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
  }

  handleScroll = () => {
    this.setState({ top: 100 }, function() {
      console.log(this.state.top);
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ minHeight: '2700px' }} onScroll={this.handleScroll}>
        <span>{'test comp'}</span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

MyComp.propTypes = {
  top: PropTypes.number
};

export default MyComp;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.App {
   height: 2000px; 
}

class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleScroll = this.handleScroll.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        window.addEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll);
    }

    handleScroll() {
        document.querySelector("body").style.backgroundColor = "pink";
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                Scroll to turn page pink :)
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I tested the code in iOS safari and chrome and the event fires as expected. It also works in OSX chrome and safari. So I dont think it has something to do with React.

In your code, you are trying to listen to `scroll` event in two places: `window` and `div`(2700px min height). You won't be scrolling anything in the `div` as its height adjusts according to its children in your example. So in this example the `onScroll` on `div` does not work.

The reason why you are not getting the `scroll` event on `window` is probably because in mobile view you are not scrolling the window / body, instead, maybe you are scrolling inside some div or other containers. And scroll event does not bubble on elements: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll